# Getting information from sites

Tags: actionscript-3, air, ria

I am new to **AIR** and trying to develop an app which will show the number of messages and comments a user got an **DeviantArt** . But i dont know how to get info about an specific object from a site.Also the site owners alow it or not ?.I am using ActoinScript 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try using deviantart API:

https://www.deviantart.com/developers/

and this part in particular:

https://www.deviantart.com/developers/oembed

Im not shure if you can get "number of messages and comments", but deviantart API is where i would start looking.